# Select average and group by doesn't work with window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to select the average rating among all reviews, but also computing values such as total number of reviews, number of reviews grouped by rating, and the percentage of each rating group (e.g. "5": 10, "4": 7, "3": 5)

Problem is, the average rating is calculated incorrectly.

SQL

```sql
SELECT
       rating,
       count(*) as rating_count,  /* number of ratings per group(e.g. 5: 10, 4: 7, 3: 5) */
       avg(rating) over() as rating_avg, /* average rating among all reviews */
       count(*) * 100 / sum(count(*)) over() as rating_share, /* percentage share of the rating group */
       sum(count(*)) over() as total_reviews
FROM post_review
WHERE post_id = 1
GROUP BY rating;
```

Sample data

```
post_id, rating
1, 5,
1, 3,
1, 5,
```

Expected `rating_avg`: `4.33`

Resulted `rating_avg`: `4`

**Question:**
I know, that `avg(rating) over() as rating_avg,` is not a correct statement for selecting the average rating in this case and I can't come up with a proper solution.

Is that possible to do all those computations in one SQL statement?

EDIT:
Detailed Result

```
rating | rating_count | rating_avg | rating_share | total_reviews
__________________________________________________________________
3      |1             | 4          | 33.33        | 3
5      |2             | 4          | 66.67        | 3
```

Comment: How is resulted rating_avg 4 from this data and this sql.  I would expect 5!

Comment: WHERE post_id = 1

Comment: my mistake, wrong id. Every row has post_id=1

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a cte, instead of window functions.  Something like this:

```
with cte as
(SELECT avg(rating) rating_avg,
count(*) total_reviews, post_id 
FROM post_review 
WHERE post_id = 1
GROUP BY post_id
)
SELECT rating,
count(*) as rating_count,
cte.rating_avg,
(count(*) * 100)::numeric / cte.total_reviews::numeric as rating_share,
cte.total_reviews
FROM post_review 
inner join cte ON post_review.post_id = cte.post_id
WHERE post_review.post_id = 1
GROUP BY rating, cte.rating_avg, cte.total_reviews;
```

The problem with your SQL is the GROUP BY.  The average rating is 4 because the GROUP BY condenses the two ratings of 5 into 1, so that the average is the average of 5 and 3 (=4) rather than 5, 5, and 3.

### Edit

As an alternative using `sum over()` you can do:

```
SELECT 
       rating,
       count(*) as rating_count, 
       sum(rating * count(*)) over() / sum(count(*)) over() as rating_avg, 
       count(*) * 100 / sum(count(*)) over() as rating_share, 
       sum(count(*)) over() as total_reviews
FROM post_review
WHERE post_id = 1
GROUP BY rating;
```

Comment: oh, I see. But why does it calculate the `avg` for the grouped values, but `count` for the whole table when used with `over`?

Comment: You are not using `over` with `count`.  You are doing `sum over()`